# curl command in .net

Tags: json, vb.net, curl

I have a curl command I was given and trying to convert and use it in .net. I have tried many different scenarios but this was the closest one I thought would work. Anyone know what I am doing wrong? the response back si saying invalid API Key

```
Curl COMMAND = https://api.com/api/v1/scores --data "token=YOUR_API_TOKEN"

    Dim request As HttpWebRequest = HttpWebRequest.Create("https://api.com/api/v1/groups")
    request.Proxy = Nothing
    request.Method = "GET"
    request.ContentType = "application/json"
    request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + Convert.ToBase64String(New ASCIIEncoding().GetBytes(String.Format("{0}={1}", "Token", personalaccesstoken))))

    'create the response and reader
    Dim Response As HttpWebResponse = request.GetResponse
    Dim ResponseStream As System.IO.Stream = Response.GetResponseStream

    'Create Stream reader
    Dim StreamReader As New System.IO.StreamReader(ResponseStream)
    Dim data As String = StreamReader.ReadToEnd
    StreamReader.Close()

    'get the data
    jsonString = data.ToString.Replace("'", "''")
```

Comment: "in C#" - that's Visual Basic.

Comment: Sorry, I switch between C# and .net all the time and was late when I posted this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up resolving this issue with the following code.

```
    Dim request As HttpWebRequest = HttpWebRequest.Create(apiURI)
    request.Proxy = Nothing
    request.Method = "POST"
    request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"

    Dim postData As String = "token=22222222222222222"
    Dim encoding As ASCIIEncoding = New ASCIIEncoding()
    Dim byte1 As Byte() = encoding.GetBytes(postData)
    request.ContentLength = byte1.Length
    Dim newStream As Stream = request.GetRequestStream()
    newStream.Write(byte1, 0, byte1.Length)
    Dim Response As HttpWebResponse = request.GetResponse
    Dim ResponseStream As System.IO.Stream = Response.GetResponseStream

    'Create Stream reader
    Dim StreamReader As New System.IO.StreamReader(ResponseStream)
    _jsonString = StreamReader.ReadToEnd
    StreamReader.Close()
```